# Data Transfer Objects and Reporting

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, data-transfer-objects

I have these scenario:

```
//This class maps to the "Item" table in the database
public class Item
{
   public int itemID { get; set;}
   public string itemName { get; set; }
   public int quantity { get; set; }
}

//Items record are returned from the database as list    
List<Item> items = ItemDAO.GetItems();
```

I want to generate a report that include aggregate values (from query/Stored Procedure)

```
ItemID| ItemName | Qty | QtySoldThisMonth | QtySoldThisYr
-----------------------------------------------------------
123   | Vit. C   |  20 |   55             |    400
239   | Maloxin  |  25 |   12             |    210
```

The Item class does not have these extra fields
This would have been easier with datatable which could have varying number of columns but I am using a list

Please, how would I go about this

Comment: why don't you use anonymous types? http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/61/posts/11203/anonymous-types-in-c-or-vb-net.aspx

Comment: QtySoldThisMonth and QtySoldThisYr are generated values. there can't be column for this. do u have any Date column in your table?

Comment: @Pranalee why date column? I know how to get those values, displaying them in my report is the issue

Comment: @Shoaib Shaikh Thanks for the link. I have read the content and it added to my knowledge. But can you return an anonymous type in ItemDAO.GetItemsByXXX()?

Comment: no you can't return anonymous types out of any method. but you can bind anonymous types to UIControls

Comment: I knew. I was just putting it back at you. To do that I would have to bypass my BLL and access my DAL/DAO directly

Comment: Appreciation to all, I have learnt today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always create another DTO specifically for that aggregated view and use that in your reports.

A little more general solution than a specific DTO for each view would be to create a DTO for reports on Item and use a collection of fields instead of class properties to store aggregate values in the DTO.

For instance:

```
 class AggregatedReportField {
     public string FieldName { get; set; }
     public decimal FieldValue { get; set; }
 }

 class ItemReportDTO {

     public Dictionary<string, AggregatedReportField> ReportFields { get; private set; }

     public ItemReportDTO()
     {
         ReportFields = new Dictionary<string, AggregatedReportField>();
     }

     public void Add(AggregatedReportField field)
     {
         if (!ReportFields.ContainsKey(fieldl.FieldName))
              ReportFields.Add(field.FieldName, field);
     }
 }
```

in your DAO, you would then first get the values from the database, create AggregatedReportField instances for each value and add them with a name to your DTO. In your report, you would then have to refer to your aggregated values with DTO.ReportFields["SomeValue"].FieldValue.

the code above is just an example and contains a few bad practices (exposed Dictionary<>).

Comment: that means for every variation of my report I have to create a new DTO?

Comment: you can go that way, yes. I updated my answer with another, more generic solution using a dictionary<>.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to separate entities (like item) and report rows (that contains additional fields).

I think, that you have to options:

1. Create separate class to represent each report (or row of the report)
2. Create class to represent all reports (it will contain metadata about columns and all data)

What you should choose depends on your requirements. These reports can use DAO and aggregate values in java code, or call stored functions directly without working with DAO.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case if you want some BLL class library to give you compiled reports in List of DTOs you should be create specialized DTOs for report. all you can do is to use class inheritance to avoid redundant code. That is all you can have at it best.

```
public class AggregatedItem:Item
{
public int QtyMonth {get;set;}
public int QtyYear {get;set;}
}
```

Regards.